# PFFacebookUtils.h compilation errors in Xcode 8.2 with latest parse libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I see that when upgrading PFFacebookUtils to the latest version v4-1.10.0 with the compatible versions of Parse and Bolts frameworks, I keep getting compilation errors. The recommended solutions I tried are upgrading Parse, Bolts libraries and XCode (I have 8.2), but still these compilation errors don't go away.

There are solutions on dealing with every compilation error, but I don't know if fixing a framework's header file like that is the right way (ideally I don't want to be touching a library header to fix issues like this).

[image: PFFacebookUtils.h compilation errors]

There are solutions like [Facebook login on iOS with Parse & cocoapods errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848301/facebook-login-on-ios-with-parse-cocoapods-errors) for solving similar errors, but want to see the right way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution. The best way to avoid these mysteries is to use the latest Parse Facebook SDK with the latest Parse build available for download. Error disappeared in that case.